# How to run anaconda 3 after install

Tags: anaconda, windows-8

I'm very new to anaconda and i just installed anaconda3 and i didn't choose the "add path" in the installation because it says "not recommended" and now i totally regret it because now i am confused how to run the anaconda . I've googled and most of them are saying to add path and run anaconda from cmd , maybe my searching skill isn't good enough or i'm just unlucky but i can't find any help on the internet how to run anaconda without cmd .

Edit : i forgot to mention that i'm using Windows 8 and i can't find any anaconda program in windows start menu nor in desktop, that's why i'm asking this.

Quick question before i reinstall anaconda and choose the "add path" during installation . How do i run anaconda if i didn't add path during installation ?

Answer (score 0):

Since nobody is answering (yet) , problem solved , just uninstall and reinstall anaconda and check the "add path" during installation to add the path to system . Then anaconda can be easily accessed through cmd . Type `anaconda-navigator` in cmd to launch the navigator.